# There is a strange jump when using parallax scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am trying to make a parallax scroll, but there seems to be a strange jump at around 100px, after scrolling back up. It works fine when I take the background image out.

Note: only on largest media query - open jsfiddle and extend the run area to largest possible until css style is applied.

Note: cannot upload image to jsfiddle, substituted with 'background-color:' - see `.home-bg{` to uncomment background-image and use a sample image for testing.

```
.home-bg{
padding: 20% 0%;
/* where the image would be - use sample image, cannot upload this one to jsfiddle
background-image: url(images/homebg.jpg);
*/
background-color: #ff0000;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: none;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2 ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.2 ease;
transition: all 0.2 ease;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j4rcd4ys/

Comment: Can you atleast give us enough details to duplicate the problem?

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: And you can use these as a place holder image for your fiddle: http://lorempixel.com/400/200/